# How can I complain against someone when my evidence was obtained from an unethical source?

Tags: complaint, whistle-blowing

A part of my IT job I take upon myself is to sieve through outgoing employee emails to remove confidential and personal information before handing over the account to the succeeding person.

One fateful occasion, I found a strange email in the inbox with salary information that was sent from employee X to the HR manager, and in turn forwarded by the HR manager to the email account owner (who is now an ex-employee). It appears that the HR manager had sent the salary information to employee X to work on some document formatting.

This raises the alarm.

In order to obtain more evidence, I logged into their email accounts and searched for the correspondences. Eventually I ended up finding more such cases between 3 other employees, together with the HR manager. Altogether 12 cases breach of trust; 6 sowing discord; and 3 asking others to do her job.

I wanted to report on misconduct but I am worried about my unethical access. As an IT personnel, I have authorised access to all systems, but I feel I could have consulted with a director before proceeding with the search. I have no idea how the management will think/act if I reveal this. What should I consider for protecting myself while be able to do justice?

**EDIT**: At which level (manager, director, or a particular department) would "snooping around" be legal? Or can make a legal decision to search?

**EDIT 2**: The answers thus far uses the legal explanations and the simple "ask your boss". I have done a Google search and it appears that in the case where law is in place, you cannot "ask your boss". The only legal way is to ask the email owners to grant access (but I still think there is a grey area: who gives permission to view ex-employee emails?). Whereas in the absence of a law, it is not clear who has the ethical authority i.e. which boss is it?

**EDIT 3**: Due to the majority *enthusiasm* for policy of minding-my-own-business and self-protection before the law (which I must admit I find rather surprising), I feel that the answers have deviated substantially from my intended main theme of "how to bring justice" to "problem with unethical evidences".

Anyway, I do appreciate that the short answer is I cannot do anything (at least under majority of country laws). Thanks for the answers. To some of the commenters/answerers, I regret that I am unable to provide more details regarding my position in the company and the nature of the misconduct I am complaining about etc. thus making this question a bit of a guess in the wild.

Comment: Don't worry about getting fired; the NSA will hire you for your flexible morals an blatant disregard for any notions of privacy. I think you may actually have a promising career intelligence sector!

Comment: Discussion moved to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18316).

Comment: There is so much wrong with this that there is no point in making another answer. I would like some clarification though: you have judged the HR manager with *"12 cases breach of trust; 6 sowing discord; and 3 asking others to do her job."* Yet the actions she has taken aren't against the law. As far as I can tell, you've invented a set of rules, and then applied them to her, and are asking us how to help you have her punished for breaking your made up rules. She has the authority to have others work on salary documents. *What is your authority?*

Comment: My issue with this is "A part of my IT job *I take upon myself* is to sieve through outgoing". You shouldn't even be clearing out confidential information. I'm sure you have an IT policy for that.

Comment: My personal rule is "Even though I have the power to know, I don't want to know, because then I would be responsible for knowing." Some don't understand that this is actually the right attitude, not that I am being lazy. Even further, you might not be able to do anything about it, even though you feel like you should. This is the situation you are in. You cannot do anything.

Comment: "A part of my IT job I take upon myself is to sieve through outgoing employee emails to remove confidential and personal information before handing over the account to the succeeding person." What are you, Yogi Berra now?

Comment: Your edits are changing the question entirely. Maybe you should ask another question, "Who in a company can decide to read employee emails?" and go from there. (But your answers here will still be correct.)

Comment: Who asked you to remove this information, if you were not asked to do that, you have your answer.  Go about it another way, strongly suggest an adult be done, do a backup before you announce anything, then since your tasked to do this create the report. It's never just  One bad apple sending out PPI

Comment: You should also stop your snooping until your given that task by your supervisor.

Comment: *If* the HR representative in question is the same one "sitting in" during your performance review [**from this question**](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23078/is-it-common-to-have-hr-sit-in-during-performance-review), you may do well to quietly and quickly cease and desist all activities you've described (which honestly would be wise to do *regardless*). I see zero-chance of a good outcome from this if that is the case, and quite the contrary; this could turn ugly *quickly*.

Comment: Unless authorized the mere fact that you are reading other peoples email, could be a firing offence on its own.  Your job is on stake here.

Comment: Your EDIT2 is not necessarily/always true. Depending on the country and applicable laws, a company can legally state (e.g. in an employment agreement) that it has the right to look at emails in the company mail server. So the people in charge can then ask an IT person to do so.

Comment: Please tell your manager about this. The company needs to know that you have exceeded your authority. I believe you need to be terminated. This is no longer about you but everyone else who needs to be protected from *you*.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, it appears that you are snooping through closed mailboxes without any permission or authorization from your management.  In my opinion, this is misconduct equal to or greater than any of the perceived offenses that you mention.

I'm assuming that you aren't privy to every conversation held by the HR manager.  Maybe this person has approval to work with one or more outside individuals for purposes of document formatting and the like.   Maybe the things that you view as a "breach of trust" are perfectly OK from the organization's standpoint.   (I won't even get into the "asking others to do her job" comment.)   The point that I'm trying to make is that you're trying to do someone else's job, and that you are commiting the same violations that you're trying to prevent (breach of trust, for example) in your own actions.

Do not take this to management if you value your job, and by all means, stop snooping through email that doesn't belong to you unless you have specific written permission from your supervisor authorizing this.  You may have access to sensitive information, but make no mistake, this does not automatically mean that you can look through it and act upon anything that you find.

Comment: You mentioned supervisor. At which level of a supervisor would be able to make that decision to search?

Comment: This depends on the organization.  I'm an IT Director - my firm's equivalent of CIO - and I would not authorize any of my staff to look through a user's email without express instructions to do so from either HR or senior management.   If I found that a member of my staff were participating in this sort of fishing expedition, a write-up would be the minimum action that I would take.   I have worked for less ethical organizations that routinely snooped through individual email accounts, but even in those organizations the action was initiated by a senior manager and not an IT staff member.

Comment: @Jake Generally someone with authority over both yourself and the 'suspect' in question.

Comment: @Roger So if you were in my position, who would you seek permission from? Does it also depends on the rank of the HR Manager?

Comment: You're missing what I'm saying.  You CANNOT act upon the things that you have found.  If you think it's important to do this -in the future-, you should obtain approval -in advance- from your supervisor before looking through any other email accounts.

Comment: Think of it like this. You're your network's detective. When someone with authority (basically someone higher up the hierarchy than the person being investigated) asks you to investigate something, you have all the access and privileges necessary to do so. This is actually a pretty cool perk. Unfortunately your vigilante search for problems is HIGHLY ILLEGAL in most of the modern world. What HR did may or may not even be an issue. They could be acting on the advisement of higher ups. Even if it's the worst case what you've done far out weighs their actions. Unless you're told to, don't dig.

Comment: @Roger that was my point. Who should I obtain approval -in advance-? If this forum does not deal with laws, how about from an ethical view point? Because you are an IT Director, I thought you would be able to give a more credible analysis why the chosen person can authorise or not.

Comment: @Jake, it depends upon the organization, as I said.  The head of your IT Department should be able to help you make this decision if your immediate supervisor can't assist.

Comment: @Jake: The question, "do we read employees' email without cause?" is a very top-level policy, the CEO or another C-level role with responsibility for IT security should make it. However, that decision being made, lower-level people should be aware of it. Your immediate supervisor should be aware of it (or can find out from their immediate supervisor and so on), so the advanced approval you seek should be at that level. This isn't a matter for going over your manager's head, since your manager should be in the loop of whether this is part of your duties or not. Follow chain of command.

Comment: ... conversely, if a particular investigation were instigated by a C-level executive, then *they* might choose to skip the chain of command if only because your immediate supervisor might be a possible suspect and so they want as few people warned as possible. But that's their decision from the top of the hierarchy: you at the bottom of the hierarchy shouldn't be seeking that out.

Comment: @Jake: I think you still missed their point. You shouldn't be asking **anyone** for approval. You should be minding your own business unless directed to look for these things.

Comment: @RualStorge  I'm not sure about other first-world countries, but it's actually not illegal in the U.S. It can certainly (and is very likely to) get you fired, but it isn't illegal. Most companies here state in their company policies that there is no expectation of privacy in company e-mail accounts or even on company computer equipment at all. This is also the case for U.S. government employees.

Comment: @reirab It's true that employees generally don't have a right to privacy on company computers so monitoring isn't generally illegal. But an employer that found out about an IT staffer going on unauthorized investigations could plausibly file criminal charges against that IT staffer under the Computer Fraud and Abuse Act for "intentionally exceeding authorized access".

Comment: @JoelEtherton Then maybe I don't really get your point. If nobody asks anyone for approval, who will, for no reason, issue any approval (to invade)? I think there has to be someone who should be *encouraged* to raise issues and set things right? Anyway, I have marked this answer as accepted.

Comment: @Jake: In your own comment is the information that answers your own question. `for no reason`. There must be a reason. If you have suspicions that something is afoul without looking through peoples' email, then you should notify your supervisor immediately. Everything else, you should mind your own business.

Answer (score 40):

> A part of my IT job I take upon myself is to sieve through outgoing employee emails to remove confidential and personal information before handing over the account to the succeeding person.

[tl;dr answer - why, oh why?]

Stop right there. Leaving aside the issue of not having official sanction to do this, and having picked up a lot of confidential information you are not entitled to have, what do you mean by "handing over the account to the succeeding person"? Do employees not have individual outgoing mail accounts? Do you recycle stuff so that a new employee could reasonably stumble across their predecessor's work? That appears to be a major problem in itself.

- Assuming you weren't doing what you do, could users ever have unintentional  access to potentially confidential mails sent by other people?
- Given that you "remove confidential information", how do you know you haven't accidentally removed something important, eg. evidence for or against wrongdoing which might subsequently be demanded by a court?
- How can anyone trust email for security and honesty if the system allows you and your fellow sysadmins to dip in and change stuff?

Basically you haven't just read stuff you weren't entitled to, you (as a result of a dysfunctional set up) have undermined the whole integrity of the email system in the company. The right thing to do would be to get the email system changed so that outgoing personal messages are never sent from generic accounts, making your sanitisiation unnecessary - but justifying that change is going to get management asking questions which could cost you your job.

Comment: “Do employees not have individual outgoing mail accounts? Do you recycle stuff so that a new employee could reasonably stumble across their predecessor's work?” I assumed that this was for e-mail addresses that aren’t specific to a given person, e.g. human-resources@company.com.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Typically modern companies generic accounts aren't shared anymore, instead when you email human-resources@company.com, it redirects that email to SallyTheyHRManager@Company.com. When Sally quits her email is archived incase it's needed for legal reasons and the HR address is then forwarded to whomever takes over. The individual's address is then set so send a "I no longer work here" or forwarded to the replacement person, or a manager, or whomever is appropriate. (companies practices differ, but you avoid "catch all" boxes for both legal and practicality reasons)

Comment: @RualStorge: ah gotcha, interesting to know.

Comment: Commonly, companies archive an ex-employee's email and permit their manager access to it for some period of time, because you might have issues that were left unfinished when they left and/or need to find past correspondence.  I wouldn't generally expect it to be forwarded whole hog to the next person up, though.  Either way, I think you shouldn't have any expectation of privacy in work email, and shouldn't use work email for anything you would be bothered by someone else seeing.

Comment: @RualStorge: Can't talk to what is common, but that's quite an outdated set up to be honest. What I have been seeing more and more is that addresses like support@company.com can be accessed by everybody in the support group (even if that's just one person). In addition to this they would have their private inbox and they can choose to reply from either.

Comment: @DavidMulder That's what we do. group-mailboxes and private mailboxes. Private mailbox is never turned over to anybody else. Person leaving in a normal way can forward or export for hand-over to successor. If someone is fired on the spot his manager can get an export made by IT, if HRM and Senior Management approve. Sifting through that is supervised by someone from HRM. If someone suddenly dies or suffers a severe illness (e.g. stroke, brain-damage) that prevents hand-over, same procedure is followed, but with additional approval of the original owner (if possible) or his family required.

Comment: @Tonny: Yep, definitely agree on the 'who can access' what issues, I was just addressing the "it redirects that email to" thing RualStorge mentioned. Which would make all mails end up in a private mailbox, with the setup I described a lot of mails will stay in the 'group mailbox' and anyone within the group can always access though. (Though some people have the bad habit of making all conversations 'private'... oh well, at least the other way around rarely if ever happens (private conversations in a group inbox) )

Comment: @DavidMulder That's my experience too.

Comment: @RualStorge: we used to have a setup like the one you mention with email forwarding, and it was a nightmare.  An employee would take maternity leave,  and suddenly there was no immediate access to relevant data from a few months ago. A generic account should be precisely that,  and not a frontend for a person's personal account.

Answer (score 11):

> What should I consider for protecting myself while be able to do
>   justice?

**Find a good lawyer.**

This answer may not be applicable in all juristdictions, but at least in Central Europe what you do is probably completely **ILLEGAL***. I am sure it is at least in Germany and the Czech Republic.

Purposeful pinpoint searches, requested by management and perhaps approved (or requested) by court is tghe only legal (if questionable) setting in which you, as an employee, can read through a limited subset of one's mail. In the above named countries the employee must know or express consent to the fact that his mail are being scrutinized.

Reading your coworkers' e-mail systematically without any consent at all is inexcusable considering the ethicality only.

And the answer is: your company should be protecting itself from you, not the other way around.

(*) I just couldn't stress the word *illegal* enough.

Answer (score 11):

Typically one does *not* search through *anything* without authorization from a lawful authority. Within a company this would probably be the board of directors and/or the CEO *backed up by your AUP* - That is to say that your employees have agreed to this beforehand.

In a very clear sense you've breached your duty of trust (or as I like to say, the *great responsibility* that comes with the *great power* of being an IT Manager and Operator. You've abused both your positional power and the powers vested in you to do your job.

In a very real sense this is *precisely* why a forensics trained IT professional has to work within a very strict set of rules, since in many cases, what you've found is probably legally useless.

Outside legal issues (And I find this varies widely), if employees believe that their work emails can be monitored without a proper procedure, they're likely  to simply switch to private email accounts anyway, and it may affect morale. This may also have office-political implications, but that's a whole another story.

What's the *right* way to do this?

1. Make it clear to start with, that you have a right to check employee email if there's a certain suspicion of wrongdoing. Make the requirements to do this clear, and have at *least* two people do the investigation *after* it has been authorised by the relevant authority. Have this in your AUP
2. Decide very clearly *who* the relevant authority is, both to request such an investigation and in order to authorize it. Where possible separate these roles as much as possible. In short, make it VERY difficult for someone to just rifle through someone elses email *and* make sure there's a clear chain of command to authorize it. It always helps to have someone who is fairly neutral to help decide when this is needed.
3. Have a log of your investigation including what triggered the investigation, what you found and where. Keep backups of relevant mail stores (Ideally on read only media) at the start of the investigation, and ensure that there's a clear chain of custody.

While its UK specific (And I'm more familiar with the way things are done in the commonwealth) [findlaw UK](http://www.findlaw.co.uk/law/employment/other_employment_law_topics/500160.html) has a nice, comprehensive article on this. While in the US, there's [apparently no right to privacy](http://www.rbs2.com/email.htm) (Better citation required!), its still not best practice, and might lead to other issues.

Comment: Regarding the U.S., it's pretty much the same as what you described for the U.K. If e-mail accounts are not private, it needs to be in the company policy that employees are made aware of and agree to that they have no expectation of privacy on company computer or e-mail systems. This is the policy of most U.S. companies as well as the U.S. federal government, though. If such policies are not in place, though, any evidence obtained would be inadmissible in court. Forensic investigators follow a similar chain of custody here as what you described.

Comment: Well I'm forensics/security trained, so my answer is heavily coloured by that. If your evidence isn't good enough to hold up in court, it is garbage.

Comment: Agreed. I'm also trained in forensics and security. I was mostly just confirming that procedures in the U.S. are almost identical to what you described for the U.K. for almost identical reasons.

Answer (score 8):

> The answers thus far uses the legal explanations and the simple "ask
>   your boss". I have done a Google search and it appears that in the
>   case where law is in place, you cannot "ask your boss". The only legal
>   way is to ask the email owners to grant access (but I still think
>   there is a grey area: who gives permission to view ex-employee
>   emails?). Whereas in the absence of a law, it is not clear who has the
>   ethical authority i.e. which boss is it?

Whenever you don't know the scope of your job, you need to talk to your boss. In this case, your immediate boss - the one who has the responsibility to tell you what your job is, and what it is not.

Go to your boss now, and ask what you are supposed to be doing about looking through emails. And ask what you are supposed to do if you find something suspicious.

Taking it upon yourself to "sieve through outgoing employee emails to remove confidential and personal information" may or may not be what your boss/company wants you to do. Doing it anyway, without knowing if it's actually part of your job, puts *you* at risk.

Answer (score 5):

It was wrong to take responsibilities like this upon yourself. If you were *Information Security*, *Assets Protection*, *Auditing*, or some similar role in your company, you would likely either already have authorization for this, or know the process for getting authorization, or know how to report something suspicious. Even they wouldn't be able to just go look at whatever they like.

You can't report the incident with how you have accessed the information without getting yourself in trouble. However, there are some options you have.

1. Show a great amount of Integrity and talk to your supervisor about the whole situation. Come clean. You should expect punishment, don't make excuses or fight it. You already seem to know what you did was wrong.
2. Suggest concerns that people are sending out sensitive information. This will be handled appropriately and you may be found out.
3. Ask your manager(or whatever supervisor would have enough power) if he would like you to have this responsibility. If yes, catch it next time it happens.
4. See if you, or suggest to somebody else in HR, can send out reminders of company policy to the general email users, along with encouraging reporting any issues.
5. Speak to the victims personally and see if they bring anything up. Encourage them to report it if they do.
6. Do nothing.

Most importantly, *with the exception with a yes on #3*, stop cleaning up the emails. If there is a need in the company for the position you are trying to perform it should become apparent soon. Doing #2 will help that along.

Comment: Even if they were infosec, auditing, etc, it would still be wrong to take on this role themselves, and without authorization from executives of the business (or court order).

Comment: @atk True, I meant to say if he had one of those roles he would likely already have authorization, or know the process to get authorization. I'll re-word it some.

Comment: not necessarially!  Such access is more likely to be restricted to individuals in such roles,  but (a)  not everone in those roles will know how to get access,  especially in larger organizations,  and (b) many individuals in those roles do not already have such access. Nonetheless, you are otherwise spot on,  and I thought you already had my upvote :-)